# How do I keep html display on while hovering on itself?

Tags: html, css

I found this solution here earlier.

```
.hiding {
    display: none;
}

.trigger:hover + .hiding {
    display:table-row;
}
```

It hides a table row then displays it when hovering over another table row (class trigger).

Question: I would like to have class `hiding` to show when it hovers over itself also. Currently it goes back to `display:none` when you are no longer hovering over class `trigger`.

Comment: Do you have fiddle to mess with? Tried anything yourself by now?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `+` which is an adjacent element selector, what I would suggest you is wrap the element `.hiding` inside another element say class `.test` and than alter your selectors like

```
.test .hiding {
    display: none;
}

.test:hover .hiding {
   display: table-row;
}

.trigger:hover + .test .hiding {
    display:table-row;
}
```

So what we are doing here is we are hiding the element nested inside the `.test` which in this case is `.hiding` and than we use the second selector with `:hover` to reveal the `.hiding` when element with `.test` is hovered(As it is present, but empty as `.hiding` is `display: none;`) and last but not the least we add `.test` after `+` in 3rd declaration, just to be sure it doesn't break the rules as `.hiding` is no more adjacent to `.trigger`, we have `.test` as an adjacent element to `.trigger`

Comment: Very nice! Learning tons of html/css but got stuck on this bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is to wrap each group of `.trigger` and `.hiding` elements within a `tbody`, and base the show/hide behaviour on the the `:hover` of that `tbody`:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="trigger">
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hiding">
            <td>hidden text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!-- and so on... -->
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tbody .hiding {
    display: none;
}

tbody:hover .hiding {
    display: table-row;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8pzUK/).

Comment: This will fail, he is using `display: none;`

Comment: This will indeed "work" but introduces a host of unnecessary markup. Case in point: http://jsfiddle.net/8pzUK/1/

Comment: @xec He edited after I commented :) but this one is perfectly good

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this with css only. You need jquery or javascript

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".trigger").hover(function () {
       $(this).css({"display" : "table-row"});
       //or u can add class like this
       //$(this).addClass("");
   },function () {
       //if you want return back, you can do here
   });
});
```

If you do not return hover function, It will keep that hovering state.

Comment: you are changing the display value of the hovered element (i.e. the already visible one...) why?